# Firebase messaging site navigation not working when notification is "hidden" in notifications center (windows 10)

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is a demo project (not my)
https://peter-gribanov.github.io/serviceworker/
When you click Register you receive an FCM token. After that you can send yourself a browser push notification (click Send). It shows just fine and if you click immediately it opens the site. But if you wait for the notification to "hide" in notifications center (right lower corner in windows 10) the click does not pass to the site (service worker is not called), just disappers.
On the page the notification is shown like this:

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
    Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
              // Copy data object to get parameters in the click handler
              payload.data.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload.data));

              registration.showNotification(payload.data.title, payload.data);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                // registration failed :(
                showError('ServiceWorker registration failed', error);
            });
        }
    });
```

(The source code is here https://github.com/peter-gribanov/serviceworker/blob/master/app.js)

(Windows 10, Chrome)